# Insert count objects fields in Array Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get a problem in Django Rest Framework.

```
class FeedDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserFeedSerializer(read_only=True)
    comment_count = SerializerMethodField(default=0)
    comment_list = CommentFeedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Feed
        fields = [
            'id',
            'comment_count',
            'comment_list',
        ]
    def get_comment_count(self, obj):
        comment_count = Comment.objects.filter(feed=obj.id, parent__isnull=True).count()
        return comment_count
```

This is the CommentFeedSerializer I've created:

```
class CommentFeedSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = comment_detail_url
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'url',
            'id',
            'comment',
            'posted_on',
        ]
```

With this Serializer I've done, API will render like this:

```
"comment_count": 2,
"comment_list": [
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comments/2/",
    "id": 2,
    "comment": "haha",
    "reply_count": 0,
    "posted_on": "2017-11-24T10:23:28.353000Z"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comments/1/",
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "Good",
    "reply_count": 1,
    "posted_on": "2017-11-24T09:54:48.680000Z"
  }
]
```

But this is very hard to manage. So I want to put comment_count into comment_list: commentlist like below How can I do that?

```
"comment_list": [
  "comment_count": 2,
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comments/2/",
    "id": 2,
    "comment": "haha",
    "reply_count": 0,
    "posted_on": "2017-11-24T10:23:28.353000Z"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comments/1/",
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "Good",
    "reply_count": 1,
    "posted_on": "2017-11-24T09:54:48.680000Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: `[comment_count:1, {}]` does not have valid syntax in JSON.

Comment: Fixed to clear. @hoefling

Comment: The quotes are not the problem here - run `$ python -c "import json; json.loads('[\"comment_count\": 2]')"` in the terminal to see what I mean. You try to mix a list with a dictionary, this won't work.